# Batch : read lines from a file having spaces in its path

Tags: command-line, batch-file

To read lines from a file, in a batch file, you do :

```
for /f %%a in (myfile.txt) do (
    :: do stuff...
)
```

Now suppose you file is in `C:\Program Files\myfolder`

```
for /f %%a in ("C:\Program Files\myfolder\myfile.txt") do (
    echo %%a
)
```

Result :

```
C:\Program Files\myfolder\myfile.txt
```

This seems to interpret the given path as a string, and thus `%%a` is your given path.

Nothing about this in the documentation I have found so far. 
Please someone help me before I shoot myself.

Comment: Until someone comes up with a better answer, COPY "C:\Program Files\myfolder\myfile.txt" temp.txt, your for loop, then DEL temp.txt

Comment: @Gilbert : hoping it's not a file named "my file.txt"...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation you get when you type `help for` tells you what to do if you have a path with spaces.

> ```
> For file names that contain spaces, you need to quote the filenames with
> double quotes.  In order to use double quotes in this manner, you also
> need to use the usebackq option, otherwise the double quotes will be
> interpreted as defining a literal string to parse.
> ```

By default, the syntax of `FOR /F` is the following.

```
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (file-set) DO command [command-parameters]
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ("string") DO command [command-parameters]
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('command') DO command [command-parameters]
```

This syntax shows why your `type` workaround works.  Because the single quotes say to execute the `type` command and loop over its output.  When you add the `usebackq` option, the syntax changes to this:

```
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (file-set) DO command [command-parameters]
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('string') DO command [command-parameters]
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (`command`) DO command [command-parameters]
```

Now you double quote paths to files, single-quote literal strings, and put backticks (grave accents) around commands to execute.

So you want to do this:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%a in ("C:\Program Files\myfolder\myfile.txt") do (
    echo %%a
)
```

Comment: I missed that part of the documentation. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

```
for /f %%a in ('type "C:\Program Files\myfolder\myfile.txt"') do (
    echo Deleting: %%a
)
```

Don't even ask me why that works.

Comment: Because TYPE displays a text file.  Your FOR loop is processing the string that represents the file contents of myfile.txt  Good find.

Comment: Yes but it works with "for /f " which is meant to be for reading files. I would have expected that to work with "for" without /f... and it does not. Anyways... Didn't shoot myself, that's the most important.

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing the below code, hoping that somebody will get benefited.

The below code take both the path having spaces and also if the read lines has spaces, it wont cause any issue of the characters after space is missing;

FOR /f "tokens=* delims=,"  %%a in ('type "C:\Progrem File\My Program"') do (
echo %%a
)