# Reading of file line by line in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have found this example [here](http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/read-lines-from-txt-file-in-dos/15219.html):

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ("GEN 0 GENERAL.html") do (
echo do my commands on %%a
pause
)
pause
```

I should read file line by line. My goal is to read and print whole line, not just one or two tokens. For me this does not work. Any idea why?
I got this output:
do my commands on GEN 0 GENERAL.html
Press any key to continue...

Solved:

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims= usebackq" %%a in ("GEN 0 GENERAL.html") do (
echo do my commands on %%a
pause
)
pause
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you loop through each line in a text file using a windows batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155932/how-do-you-loop-through-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-a-windows-batch-file). SO > computing.net

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389923/batch-read-lines-from-a-file-having-spaces-in-its-path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `usebackq` to your options list, after the `tokens` and `delims` options:

> `"tokens=* delims= usebackq"`

As you have it written, the double quotes around the filename are causing it to be interpreted as a string (and not the name of file containing strings).

Comment: OK I have it. THanks. usebackq takes the double quotes as command.