# Read lines with blank spaces from a file using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to read each line from a text file using batch.

The lines inside the file has **some blank spaces**, so this is an example of the input:

```
This is the first line
This is the second line
...
```

I'm using the following source code

```
FOR /f %%a in ("%1") do (
    @echo %%a
)
goto:eof
```

The output is the follwing:

```
This
This
...
```

I have read the following entry in Stack Overflow but is doesn't solve my issue.
[Batch : read lines from a file having spaces in its path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389923/batch-read-lines-from-a-file-having-spaces-in-its-path)

Comment: Assuming `%1` is your file name, then your posted code cannot work as you describe. Either you must be using the `"usebackq"` option, or else your IN() clause must not be quoted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this.

```
FOR /f "tokens=* delims=,"  %%a in ('type "%1"') do (
    @echo %%a
)
```

Comment: Now the code will cut off each line at the first occurance of `,`.

Answer (score 6):

Bali C and Henry Gao skirt around the issue.

Your code is terminating the value at the 1st space because FOR /F is designed to parse a string into delimited tokens. The default delimiters are space and tab. You can preserve the entire line by setting DELIMS to nothing.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%~1") do echo %%a
```

But there are still potential problems: The FOR /F loop skips empty lines, and also skips lines that begin with the EOL character (`;` by default).

The FOR command (especially the FOR /F variant) is a complicated beast. I recommend reading http://judago.webs.com/batchforloops.htm for a good summary of the nooks and crannies of the FOR command.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your delimiter for where the batch reads up to on each line

```
FOR /f "delims=;" %%a in ("%1") do (
    @echo %%a
)
```

The default delimiter for the end of the line is a semi colon. Alternatively use a character that you are not likely to see in the file like `~` or `¬` or something.

Comment: Why setting the delimiter to a strange value, why not simply setting it to nothing?

Comment: @jeb How do you set it to nothing? `"delims="` will set it to space as default won't it?

Comment: No, like dbenham shows, `"delims="` set it to nothing, only EOL can't be set this way to an empty value, `"EOL="` will set EOL to a quote. But EOL can be empty by other ways